Localized day of week to DayOfWeek enum
Currently my application stores information as plain text of the local day of week name. (e.g. Montag, Dienstag). This is quite error prone (upper, lower case). I know there is the DayOfWeek enum. How to get the localized version from the enum is well documented and covered in many questions.
Problem is the other way round. The German word to the enum. I know the primitive way a switch case. For multiple languages I may get the translations for each enum value and switch through them. Is there a native solution?

You already know how to get the localised names from a DayOfWeek, so you can just get the names of all the days, and compare them against your input string.
For example, here I am creating a Dictionary<string, DayOfWeek> with a culture-sensitive, case-insensitive equality comparer.
var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag("de");
var inputString = "Sonntag"

var formatInfo = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(cultureInfo);
var dict = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).ToDictionary(
    x => formatInfo.GetDayName((DayOfWeek)x),
    x => (DayOfWeek)x,
    StringComparer.Create(cultureInfo, true)
);
Console.WriteLine(dict[inputString]);


That's a nicer variant of the switch case approach. I am searching for a native way without translating everything

@finder2 What do you mean by a "native way" and "translating everything"? Where did I translate anything? I highly doubt there is a convenient built-in method for you to call, as this use case is relatively rare.

Yeah thought abaout a built-in name with DateFormat or something like that. But yeah. Seems the best is to map.
